# The existence of a chart that maps its domain homeomorphically onto a Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In my textbook, a topological manifold is defined to be a Hausdorff, second-countable space that is locally homeomorphic to an open set in a Euclidean space, and any such homeomorphism is called a chart. But in other books I was told that there is actually an equivalent definition for manifolds, that is, we can require a chart to be a homeomorphism onto a Euclidean space. How could this happen? I mean, in terms of the original definition, is it possible to find a chart $(U,\phi)$ on a manifold $M$ of dimension, say, $n$, such that $\phi(U)=\mathbb R^n$? Thank you.

Comment: Compose a coordinate chart whose image is an open ball in $\Bbb R^n$ with a (radial) homeomorphism between the open ball and the full $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

It's well known that $\Bbb R^n\cong B(x,r)$, where $B(x,r)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.  Here the equivalence is in the topological (or even differentiable) sense. ($r\gt0$, of course)